# how to implement agora video call invitation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

I am new to flutter I want to know the best way to implement video call invitations using agora SDK
for both sides.

```
    // joing channel
String token = await getToken("test22", 25);
await _engine.joinChannel(json.decode(token)["Token"], "test22", null, 25);
Map arguments = {
  "calleeId": 15,
  "content": "empty",
  "channelId": "test22",
};
await _client!.sendLocalInvitation(arguments);
```

I tried to use this method but I get  Unhandled Exception: sendLocalInvitation failed errorCode:1

Answer (score 1):

For in-app call notifications, you can use the Agora RTM SDK to signal the callee about the incoming call. You can refer to this link to know more about the procedure: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/rtm_invite_android